# 64bit Windows and Mac Tor Browser Bundle downloads always have the wrong sha256 hash. What is wrong?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, verification

I mostly run Ubuntu versions and never have problems verifying signatures and sha256sum on the Tor releases for Ubuntu.

However, when I attempted to put tor on a windows7 machine, `torbrowser-install-6.0.3_en-US.exe` always gives me a sha256sum of: 
`c444319129d3de300eb4d7421861cc75f03eb9b0ee00738e2cdde4d63395c0d4`.

The correct sum is   `e8ca44a4d73bc0183973e3e7abbbaf546c2a1d2cae3df58b76e929332e02a277`.

I downloaded the Windows 7 release several times on different machines and platforms and always got the same invalid hash no matter which platform I chose.

Answer (score 1):

[#19494 (Invalid SHA256 on version 6.0.1 et 6.0.2)](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19494)

> The sha256sums-unsigned-build.txt file contains the hashes of the bundles before they are signed.
>
> For the Windows bundles, you can use `osslsigncode` to remove the signature. It is available in this git repository: http://git.code.sf.net/p/osslsigncode/osslsigncode/
>
> Then you can do:
>
> ```
> $ sha256sum torbrowser-install-6.0.2_en-US.exe 
> 3a2e05304345936fd713b638612088fa0914102389c15c7bf7aa1d74803e5db8  torbrowser-install-6.0.2_en-US.exe
> $ ./osslsigncode remove-signature torbrowser-install-6.0.2_en-US.exe torbrowser-install-6.0.2_en-US.exe-unsigned
> Succeeded
> $ sha256sum torbrowser-install-6.0.2_en-US.exe-unsigned
> 697a1d592c46138f894f9c03db54393bf61dd53df1b1043844f59f7e85439d1b  torbrowser-install-6.0.2_en-US.exe-unsigned
> ```
>
> We are still working on the instructions to remove the code signing on the .dmg files. This is ticket [#18925](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18925).

If you want to verify the download, use the corresponding `.asc` file. It both validates the cryptographic hash of the file *and* allows you to ensure that the hash is provided by the the correct key (I.E. the providence of the claimed cryptographic hash of the file).

You *do* want to ensure that the cryptographic hash is actually provided to you by the correct party and not just rely on a checksum published on a website, for an example as to why this is important see what happened to [Linux Mint recently](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994) (hackers replaced their download links *and* the checksums for the isos listed on the website, signature verification would have prevented this.).